# How can I export SPSS custom tables to a specific Excel sheet without the SPSS code?

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, spss

I want to control the sheet into which the custom table output is saved, so apparently I cannot use OMS under SPSS 19 basic.  I have been using OUTPUT EXPORT, but even when I close the output before the CTABLES comment, it includes the text of that comment.  I do not want to include the CTABLE command, just the table that is produced.

Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks!
Martin

Comment: OMS is in all SPSS versions. You can suppress the generation of code in the output though through either `SET` commands or through edit -> options.

Comment: I know OMS comes with SPSS basic, and I have used OMS, but I cannot find a way to use it and specify the sheet the output goes to.  Is there a way to specify the sheet for export using OMS?

Comment: You are correct in that you can not specify a sheet in OMS, but you can use OMS to basically control everything that goes to the output. So you can use OMS to suppress everything except the CTABLES command, and then use OUTPUT EXPORT - is one potential workflow.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this with OMS is to select and suppress everything except the tables you want:

oms select all /exceptif subtypes="customtable" /destination viewer=no.